# Create class for integer value identifier and new Number

Tags: c#

I'm trying to pass some training tests with C#, but I've really stuck with this one

The task says: fix compiler error without changing of any string inside the `Function()`, create integer class to identify integer variable with specific name `myIntIdentifier` and output `myNmb` value

```
        public void Function()
        {                
             myIntIdentClass orgNumb = new Number { numbVal = 1, numbStr = "One"};
             int myNmb= orgNumb;

             Console.WriteLine(myNmb);
        }
```

Here is what I have tried:

```
    public class myIntIdentClass
    {
        public int numb { get; set; }

        public static implicit operator int(myIntIdentClass v)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    public class Number
    {
        private int intVal { get; set; }
        private string strVal { get; set; }
    }
```

but the `new Number` shows:

> 'Number' is inaccessible due to its protection level

Comment: [User-defined conversion operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/user-defined-conversion-operators?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235)

Comment: can you show your *Number* class?

Comment: @Miraziz Seems Hello, I'm not sure, how to use it in this case

Comment: @Reza Aghaei I've tried, but for me, it is not  clear how to use it without change  Value = 1, NumberString = "One"

Comment: It seems your class Number, maybe private class ?

Comment: @Miraziz Sorry, I've missed Number in post, added

Comment: @FolabiAhn Hello, sorry, It was missed in description. Please check edit

Comment: It seems your Function method is not in the same class as Number. So change number protection to public (public class Number)

Answer (score 1):

**You cannot initialize the class props because they are private.**

here you are trying to init your class using one line initializer
but your props are private, so you cannot access them.

```
 new Number { numbVal = 1, numbStr = "One"};
```

you can set the encapsulation level of the props in the Number class to public to fix this error.

```c#
   public class Number
    {
        public int intVal { get; set; }
        public string strVal { get; set; }
    }
```

By the way the convention for props is encapsulation level as public and naming in PascalCase.

And another error is that you are missing an implicit casting from Number to myIntIdentClass

Answer (score 1):

1. Hint: `private` means only accessible within the class. Change the access modifiers to `public`, or `internal`.
2. Also notice how both `Number` and `myIntIdentClass` share at least one integer property. I think the intent here is to use inheritance.
3. Lastly you need to write a user defined `implicit operator` to convert `myIntIdentClass` to integer when neeeded.

The code below fullfills the above items.

```
public class myIntIdentClass
{
    public int numbVal { get; set; }
    public static implicit operator int(myIntIdentClass my)
         => my.numbVal;
}
public class Number : myIntIdentClass
{
    public string numbStr { get; set; }
}
```